# AIX linking issue

Tags: c++, aix

I am using xlC_r on AIX. I want to use export list of one library and want to generate export definitions for all my library.

So I used **-bexpall in combination with -bE:**

But it is not exporting some definitions like - Constructor and Destructor of class but other methods of the class are getting exported.

When I see with nm I get the constructor/destructor but with dump -X64 -Tv I am not able to see them.

What is the documented behavior for -bexpall and -bE: combination?

When I used -bexpfull and -bE: it works. But the downside is it will export methods starting with an underscore.

Basically, I am combining export definitions from my current code and other library (3rd party) together into a single library i.e why I need to use -bE:  (3rd party) and -bexpall (for my own methods).

Comment: Use only one of these: -bexpall, -bexpfull, -bE:file. If you think your export file is incomplete, please quote it (it should contain 'mangled' i.e. human-unreadable names)

Comment: Actually, I want some of the export definitions from a library which is actually ".a" and provided list of exported methods in export file. And i want all my methods to be exported combined with other export file.

Comment: It would be less cryptic, if you showed the command line you used and the content of the export-file. (Edit the original post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried making Constructor and Destructor inline and it worked. I don't know the reason.